# TypeScript compiler error: Cannot initialize ActiveScript

Tags: typescript

For some reason I am getting a "Cannot initialize ActiveScript" error when I try to run tsc. Any ideas how to fix it?

I did read the other question in here, but I am already running IE11, så installing IE10 does not sound like a solution. Also I am not looking for the workaround of running it through node.

Comment: Can you start ie11 and make sure it works

Comment: IE11 works fine, I use it every day..

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an older issue but I had the same issue a few weeks back.
In my case there where two version in the following directory (0.9 and 1.0): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript#

I resolved it by removing the older version and everything started working again!

Comment: This fixed it for me.  I'm surprised this is not a more common problem.

Answer (score 0):

I started to get this error when I accidentally deleted tschost.dll, which had been next to tsc.exe (we are way back on version 1.6.2, lucky us.)  Replacing tschost.dll corrected the error.